# Missing dll Error Whle installing Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, enthought

I am trying to install python(epd_free-7.3-2-win-x86) on my PC (windows 7 - 32bit) but not able to do so. it shows error which says a DLL is missing. searched every where but could not found. i have attached an image of error message dialog.

[image]

I also tried different python installers but they show same error. I even tried installation after updating my windows but nothing worked. Please tell me what to do??

Comment: My friend is also facing the same problem. He is having Windows 8 - 32 bit.

Comment: Looks like that's possibly outdated. It appears EPD free is now called `Canopy Express` - see https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/free/

Comment: I have found the solution for it. here is it:

In my case, the DLL wasn't missing--the installer didn't have permissions to access the folder. so what i did is navigated to C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\ and right clicked on Temp. there in after going to Properties > Security on the C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp folder and given 'Everyone' the 'Full control' permission. Installer that previous had been failing now worked!

for more details : http://superuser.com/questions/478631/dll-could-not-be-run-for-msi-installers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Was facing the same problem in windows 8 - 64 bit ..
try doing this..

Go to **C:/Users//AppData/Local** .
right click on the folder **"Temp"**.
Go to **Properties**.
Go to **Security** Tab.
Click on **"Everyone"** and "**Edit"** the permission to **"full control"-> allow**.
Click apply.

try running the installer again. YOu should be good to go.

Comment: This fixed my same issue above as well.  Should mark correct!

Comment: This didn't work for me though the symptoms were similar. Turned out to be a conflicting PIP install. This fixed me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23350061/797945

Comment: Try Sunny's suggestion first to avoid changing permissions on the temp folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24168463/5936985

Answer (score 5):

Run Command Prompt as Administrator. See Image

[image]

Change directory to location of .msi file using cd command and type the name of of your file with extension i.e. .msi (see image below). You may give the complete path of file instead of changing directories.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open command line as administrator. Change directories to the folder where the file is located.

For example for me it was the following:

CD C:/Users/"MyName"/Downloads
C:/Users/"MyName"/Downloads python-3.3.3.amd64.msi

This will run the installation with admin rights and the error window will not pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can right click the msi package, choose "properties" and click the "Unblock" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Power Shell.
Just run it as administrator and then go to python-2.7.10.amd64.msi path.
then execute it by command and it will install without any problem.

### for example:

I put python installer file in **D:\Programming\language\Python**

### So:

PS C:\Windows\system32> cd D:\Programming\language\Python

PS D:\Programming\language\Python> .\python-2.7.10.amd64.msi

and ENTER

Answer (score 0):

On some systems the order matters (windows 2008 R2 for example) when also installing pip. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692067/1360853) seems to do the trick when having this error on such systems

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comment above, I have found the solution for it. here is it.

In my case, the DLL wasn't missing--**the installer didn't have permissions** to access the folder. so what I did is navigated to **C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\** and right clicked on Temp. there in after going to Properties > Security on the C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp folder and given **'Everyone'** the **'Full control'** permission. Installer that previous had been failing now worked! for more details : https://superuser.com/questions/478631/dll-could-not-be-run-for-msi-installers