# Fail to install Python 2.7.9 on a Windows google compute engine instance

Tags: python-2.7, windows-server-2008, google-compute-engine

I fired up a new Windows google compute engine instance.  It's running Windows 2008 R2, service pack 1.

I download and try running the Python .msi installer for version 2.7.9, and it fails with this error:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package.  A program required for this install to complete could not be run.  Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

I see this error for both the 64-bit and the 32-bit installer.

Has anyone else seen it or know of a work-around?

Comment: The python2.7.5 installer runs without reporting an error, but then when I look at the Python27 directory, the Scripts directory is missing!

Answer (score 9):

I reproduced your issue and I found two workarounds:

1. You can install [python 2.7.6](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.amd64.msi)  successfully without further action.
2. If you need [python 2.7.9](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/python-2.7.9.amd64.msi) you can install it deselecting pip from the install menu.
   This seems to be related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23350061/3906217) in another thread although in that case the issue is with version 3.4.

Comment: I couldn't unselect pip, the installer kept on giving me this error when trying to change the installation. Your link to 'this answer' helped as the [next most upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27334909/327074) talks about deleting the `PYTHON_HOME` environment variable which helped me

Answer (score 7):

1. Install python EXCEPT "pip"
2. Run the python install msi again and select "change"
3. Select "pip" and install the pip
   It would be works...

I think it is a priority problem into the msi package...the package seems to try to install the pip before installing python.exe. So, pip can not be installed...

Comment: This worked for me with python-2.7.11.amd64 on Windows Server 2008R2 64bit (dedicated server, not a google compute engine instance)

Comment: Using "change" to add pip didn't work for me with 2.7.9 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit. I had 2.7.11 installed and then I tried to install PIP as well via [Chocolatey PIP package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/pip).

I think my installation had got messed up because I had tried to install Python 3.4 as well as Python 2.

Then I had deleted all the Python 2 and Python 3 files in an attempt to get rid of this.

What worked for me was:

1. Editing the Environment Variables both, System and User to remove any `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH` variables
2. I also deleted the path I had to python2 in the `PATH` environment variable
3. Now (as mentioned in [Python Issue 22329](https://bugs.python.org/issue22329)) after deleting the Environment variables you can go into 'Programs and Features', click on the Python 2.7.11 (64-bit) program and then click 'Repair' - this then worked as I would expect without error.
4. Now finally I was able to go into 'Programs and Features', click on the Python 2.7.11 (64-bit) program and then click 'Uninstall'.

**Edit**: I assume this is connected with this [`PYTHON_HOME` answer to a problem with Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27334909/327074)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a dependency issue, please try to install "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)"