# Error when installing python

Tags: python, windows, installation

I was trying to install python and for some weird and unknown reason, the installation process is stopped and returns this error

> An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.21022.8",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information.

This is the first time I encountered such error. I tried 'googling' it but there seems to be no way to fix this up. Do you guys have any suggestions? I just want to install python.

Comment: Where did you download Python from, and which version did you download? Also, what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I got the link from here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404878/fail-to-install-python-2-7-9-on-a-windows-google-compute-engine-instance Any version would do though. Im using windows 7

Comment: Then go to [https://www.python.org/downloads/](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and download the version you need. "Any version would do" might be the wrong approach because Python 2 and Pyhon 3 are incompatible.

Comment: what do you mean theyre incompatible?

Comment: @HaroldDecapia: Non-trivial code written for Python 2 won't run with Python 3 and vice versa. Just a `print "Hello"` will run on Python 2, but not Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post but I recently ran into this exact same issue. 
It was caused by my machine having pending Windows updates that needed a restart to be applied.

Once you've reset your machine remove the C:\Python27 folder (this is important).

Rerun the installer and it should work with no issues :-)

Answer (score 2):

Please provide the environment you have installed.

if windows 2008 R2, because of the rights issue, you need to cancel the installation of pip, it is best not to install in C.

```
msiexec.exe /quiet /i python-2.7.10.amd64.msi ADDLOCAL=DefaultFeature TARGETDIR=D:\python27
```

Comment: i haven't installed anything yet. just downloaded the installer.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. The reason is that Python-dependent system updates need to be rebooted before they can be configured correctly

Answer (score -1):

Try [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) it has a lot of libraries already packaged in it. And it comes with **conda** : a package manager.

```
conda install my-package
```

And my-package is already installed.

Comment: I will actually use python for libsvm. Will installing anaconda work for libsvm?

Comment: Anaconda is a completely free Python distribution (including for commercial use and redistribution). It includes more than 400 of the most popular Python packages for science, math, engineering, and data analysis.
So yes it should work.