# Windows errors when I try to run "npm i"

Tags: node.js, npm

After 7 hours, I have given up. I try to run "npm i", which worked yesterday, but not today. The only thing changed in the meantime is I updated Node.js from 16 (I think) to 18. Yes, big mistake.

**The error**

This is the error I am getting when I run "npm i" in my project:

```
    npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-property-regex instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-dynamic-import instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.8: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.10.1: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm WARN deprecated consolidate@0.15.1: Please upgrade to consolidate v1.0.0+ as it has been modernized with several long-awaited fixes implemented. Maintenance is supported by Forward Email at https://forwardemail.net ; follow/watch https://github.com/ladjs/consolidate for updates and release changelog
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)       
npm WARN deprecated flat@4.1.0: Fixed a prototype pollution security issue in 4.1.0, please upgrade to ^4.1.1 or ^5.0.1.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)       
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated highlight.js@9.18.1: Version no longer supported. Upgrade to @latest
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection
 in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection
 in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.5: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection 
in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\xx\Site\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\xx\Site\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\xx\\Site\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xx\Site\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xx\Site\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xx\Site\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xx\Site\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xx\Site\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xx\Site\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xx\Site\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xx\Site\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xx\Site\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xx\Site\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xx\Site\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xx\Site\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python311\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python311\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xx\\Site\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\xx\Site\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-07T13_08_59_279Z-debug-0.log
```

**Things Ive tried**

- remove node_modules and package-lock.json
- remove node.js from Windows (with Add/Remove programs)
- revert back to latest commit (working) from yesterday
- completely removed node from Windows (npm and npm-cache files in Appdata/Roaming and node from C:/ProgramData)
- tried to remove .npmrc file but can't find it anywhere (hidden files are shown)
- uninstall and install node-sass
- cleared npm cache with force
- removed chocolately & python and reinstalled when installing node 16
- rebooted machine
- Windows Powershell in Administrator removed node-gyp (was reinstalled by installing node.js)
- Windows Powershell in Administrator npm i windows-build-tools (was deprecated)
- ran "npm ci", same error
- ran "npm i" with force

**Package.json**

This is my package.json file, in which nothing is changed since yesterday when it still worked:

```
    {
  "name": "old project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "generate:nswag:api": "nswag run config.api.nswag"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.23.0",
    "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.1.0",
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^2.0.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3.2.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "1.7.1",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "msal": "^1.3.2",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.18.2",
    "vue-material": "^1.0.0-beta-14",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
    "vuex-persist": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.21",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nswag": "^13.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {},
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
          "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "mocha": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

**NVM**

I installed this thing called "nvm". When I run "nvm list", I have a few versions. My project ALWAYS used to run on 11.10.1

1. When I run "nvm current", it says: 16.16.0
2. When I run "nvm install 11.10.1", it says already installed.
3. When I run "nvm use 11.10.1", it says Now using node v11.10.1(64-bit)
4. When I run "nvm current" again, it still says 16.16.0

What is this about? How can I fix my issue and run "npm i"?

---

**EDIT**

I have succesfully installed python 2, now my errors have changed to:

```
    npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: old-project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: jest@26.6.3
npm ERR! node_modules/jest
npm ERR!   dev jest@"^26.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jest@">=24 <25" from ts-jest@24.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/ts-jest
npm ERR!   dev ts-jest@"^24.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: the package `node-sass` is native-addon so if you don't need it remove it and that's all if you need it so you must have all the build tools including python2. some packages came precompiled so don't need for recompile but in you case probably not. and change node version almost always require recompile because abi version changed

Comment: I tried to remove it, when I do that, I get errors from other packages like jest etc.

Comment: if that the case then you must have windows build tools installed on your pc and python2 not python3. the `npm i` will compile and build the package

Comment: When I try to install Python 2, I get a Windows error:  An error occured during the installation of the assembly.

Comment: maybe is that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259990/error-when-installing-python but anyway to compile the package you need windows build tools and node-gyp all installed set up correctly.

Comment: when i run npm i windows-build-tools, it says deprecated so not sure what to do now

Comment: don't install it likes this. when you install nodejs you can check on install compile tools ... or something like that. i don't remember exactly the caption. i think its also install python2 too. maybe node-gyp too if not isntall it manully. after that you probably ready to go to compile (just check python is 2 not 3)

Comment: I managed to install python 2 finally, but now I get other errors about jest and ts-jest. Is there a way I can ever get this project to work again? Maybe do a laptop complete factory reset and clone the project from the repo again?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the logs. The `node-gyp` is looking for `python2` command, but you have `python` 3.x.

Comment: This project has always worked. I didn't uninstall python yesterday or this morning, I uninstalled it when npm i didn't work anymore. Why should I install it manually now?

Comment: If you upgraded node.js from 16 to 18 that almost certainly changes the entire dependency tree.

Comment: Im getting an error when I try to install python 2.. 

An error occured during the installation of the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Delete node modules and install all packages from package.json manually, without specifying the versions of the package

Answer (score -1):

npm WARN does not cause any errors.